# Knockout.js - loading JSON data with previous <select> value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I've written an ASP.NET MVC 4 app, using Knockout 2.2 for the UI. One of the pages has a simple table populated by a dropdown list whose selected value is passed as a parameter to an AJAX call.

A tester alerted me to some strange behaviour: if the user selects a value in the dropdown, then goes to another page and returns using the browser's back or forward button, the selected value persists in the dropdown, but the parameter passed to the AJAX call is the value of the first element in the array of dropdown options, and so the data displayed in the table is not what the user expects.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    Option:
    <select data-bind="options: options, optionsText: 'Value', optionsValue: 'Key', value: selectedOption"></select>
</div>

@* JSON representation of viewmodel for debugging purposes *@
<div> 
    <textarea style="margin-top:10px" rows="20" cols="100" data-bind="value: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></textarea>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var ViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.selectedOption = ko.observable();
        self.testArray = ko.observableArray();

        self.options = ko.observableArray([
            { Key: 1, Value: "1" },
            { Key: 2, Value: "2" },
            { Key: 3, Value: "3" },
            { Key: 4, Value: "4" },
            { Key: 5, Value: "5" }
        ]);

        ko.computed(function () {
            if (!isNaN(self.selectedOption())) {
                $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetTestArray", "Home")", { optionId: self.selectedOption() }, function (data) {
                    self.testArray([self.selectedOption(), 2, 3]);
                })
            }
        });
    }

    var viewModel = new ViewModel();

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

testArray displays as expected if I comment out the $.getJSON call in the computed observable and just set the array (in the real app, it's a collection of custom business objects). But if I include the call to the server, testArray always displays as [1, 2, 3] even if a number other than 1 is initially selected in the dropdown. If a different value is selected at this point, the observables update as expected.

I came across the 'valueWithInit' solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/BnDh6/, but I wasn't able to get it to work for my problem. I think the reason was that the element.value property was "" when the init function is called for the first time, probably because the dropdown has not been populated with the options observable array.

I've been able to work around the problem by forcing the dropdown to default to the first option on page load, but I'm still curious to see if it is possible to get the previously selected value of the dropdown and perform an AJAX call with it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, regarding the browser displaying that previously-selected value, you could try modifying the `<form>` tag to disable *autocomplete*:

```
<form autocomplete="off"></form>
```

I think you can also add this attribute to individual form elements, so you may prefer to add it only to the `<select>` element.

I don't suppose the browser in question is Safari, is it? I've found in the past that while most browsers cache the document that was loaded from the server, Safari caches the document from which you navigated away.

Because of this, I have the following on an MVC controller for a page where this has caused me problems in the past:

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "private");
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
```

You might want to wrap the above in some sort of browser-detection `if` statement, in case you wish to selectively apply it.

---

Now, as for your view-model, is that `ko.computed` a simplified representation or do you really have it declared like that? I've never seen a *computed* unattached in that manner.

My suggestion would be to remove that `computed` add a [subscription](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) to the `selectedOption` observable:

```
self.selectedOption = ko.observable();
self.selectedOption.subscribe(function(val) {

    if (isNaN(val)) {
        return;
    }

    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetTestArray", "Home")", { optionId: self.selectedOption() }, function (data) {
        self.testArray([val, 2, 3]);
    })
}
```

This subscription will only be triggered when the value held in the `selectedOption` observable is changed.

Comment: I and my tester we using IE.

Comment: Ok, but the answer is still as valid.

Comment: I used ko.computed instead of a subscription because I wanted the table to be populated with data already when the user first visits the page. In that case, the subscription wouldn't be triggered. 

I know I could populate selectedOption and testArray in the model in the controller ActionResult, but that would still result in incorrect behaviour if the user is returning to the page through the back button.